# Magento 2.3.3 + Varnish + Nginx + SSL + CentOS - 302 Too May Redirects

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, nginx, varnish, centos

Hoping there are some Varnish guru's out there that can show me my mistake here. I'm experiencing an endless 302 redirect for both the frontend and admin. Here is my configuration:

**Nginx Configuration**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}

server {
    server_name dev.mydomain.com;
    listen 8080;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
    include /home/mydomain/public_html/nginx.conf;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}

server {
    server_name dev.mydomain.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  1d;
    ssl_session_cache  shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets  off;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    error_log /home/mydomain/public_html/error_log;
    access_log /home/mydomain/public_html/access_log;

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;       #deny all other hosts
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    }

}
```

**Varnish Configuration**

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {
        set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        return (synth(750, "Permanently moved"));
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    #Bypass pages where finder applied
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "amfinder_routes=") {
        set req.http.PageUrlKey = regsub(req.url, "(\.|\?)+.*$", "");
        set req.http.PageUrlKeyPrepared = regsuball(req.http.PageUrlKey, "/", "_");

        if (std.strstr(req.http.Cookie, req.http.PageUrlKeyPrepared)) {
            return (pass);
        }
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";



    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
        set resp.status = 301;
        return (deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) {
        hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED);
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

**Magento URL & Cache Configuration**

[image: Magento URL Configuration]

[image: Magento Cache Configuration]

**Note**:
If I change the web/unsecure/base_url to http://dev.mydomain.com I can get the frontend to work and this makes sense to me because Varnish is trying to access Magento over http. The problem with this is that all my links on the site are then written as http which is bad for several reasons. Also, with this setting the admin still continues the endless 302 redirect.

Comment: You cleared varnish and Magento block cache after making your https and use_in configurations? Not a solution but one tip is that you can check you are using varnish by switching to developer mode and checking the headers - first hit you should see X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html also check your cookie domain config

Comment: @DominicXigen Yeah, I have cleared the cache and checked headers so varnish is working. I get a MISS, then a HIT.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this at [Varnish - NGINX serving all resources HTTP instead of HTTPS (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221404/varnish-nginx-serving-all-resources-http-instead-of-https-magento-2)

Since I had such a hard time finding the solution specifically for my setup I'll copy the answer here as well:

> Find the line like this in nginx.config: location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check|phpinfo).php$ { .... }
>
> Add this line: fastcgi_param HTTPS on; above: include fastcgi_params;
>
> Restart NGINX! Worked for me!

Comment: Thanks! After many things I tried, this worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing to clear cache, then try again. By the way which url is trying to redirect you as 302 ?